# How to find for specifc elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

So i append a huge list of data from a csv file ( in this case 3 rows -> one for year,month,and a value that corresponds to it )
File example:

```
2001,01,65
2001,02,56
..goes until December 2001
2002,01,45
2002,02,46
..goes until December 2002
( Almost 50 years of data just like this )
```

I append these values to a list and i am trying to make a list for each month for a specific year. So lets say Jan, how can i append all the values of jan for only a specific year lets say 2000.
Hope this made sense!

(Please don't write long codes and work on it for a long time. Only a textual way of saying that do this and then do that will help.)
I just don't know how to find a specific element in a collection of data.

Comment: "2001,01,65" - what's this?

Comment: 2001 - year
 01 - month
65 - age

Comment: Ok, so you want do this for 2000, which is not in the example file, and make a list for each month, although in the example each month has only one entry. Crystal clear so far. Please do tell us more.

Comment: I was just giving an example, my main point is to find a specific element in a collection of huge data.

Comment: Did you mean your data has 3 columns, rather than 3 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and an if condition to add it to your separate list:

```
for rows in myOriginalList:
    if row[0] == year and row[1] == month:
        newFilteredList.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have read in a row for years, a row for months, and a row for values and have them stored in `years`, `months`, and `values`:

```
filtered_list = []
query_year = 2000
query_month = 1
for year, month, value in zip(years, months, values):
    if int(year) == query_year and int(month) == query_month:
        filtered_list.append(int(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with an `if` clause for filtering:

```
csv_file = [
    "2001,01,65",
    "2001,01,23",
    "2001,02,56",
    "2002,01,45",
    "2002,02,46"
] # Just an example. In reality, you'll want to use open() on your actual file.

# prepare a CSV reader:
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, ['year', 'month', 'age'])

# read and filter the data:
january_2001_data = [row for row in reader
     if row['year'] == '2001' and row['month'] == '01']
# january_2001_data == [{'age': '65', 'month': '01', 'year': '2001'},
#                       {'age': '23', 'month': '01', 'year': '2001'}]
```

If your CSV file is really, really, *really* huge, you might have to look into something like [pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas).